# CNContactPickerViewController Navigation bar position error

Tags: ios, objective-c, cncontactviewcontroller

Occasionally I get a navigation bar of CNContactPickerViewController position error on iPhoneX.

How to fix this problem?

The source code is shown below.

```
- (void)showContactPicker {
     if (_contactPicker) {
          [_contactPicker removeFromParentViewController];
          _contactPicker = nil;
     }

     _contactPicker = [[CNContactPickerViewController alloc] init];
     _contactPicker.delegate = self;
     _contactPicker.displayedPropertyKeys = @[CNContactPhoneNumbersKey];

     [self presentViewController:_contactPicker animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Screenshot is below.
[image]

I'm sorry I can not upload image because I have not enough reputation...

Comment: CNContactPickerViewController is incredibly buggy to the point of being unusable, especially when selecting multiple contacts. Apple hasn't been interested in fixing it for years, unfortunately.